# I have a admin/posts controller, how to setup form_for for a new post page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Admin::PostsController < ApplicationController

  def new
     @post = Post.new
  end

end
```

my routes:

```
namespace :admin do
     resource :posts

  end
```

Now in my `/views/admin/posts/new.html.erb`:

What should my forms_for look like, so it posts to the `create` action?

Answer (score 6):

If memory serves, you will create a `form_for [:admin, @post]` :)

Comment: actaully it didn't work, it is going to /admin/posts/new instead of /admin/posts/create

Comment: @BlankMan: if you're doing [:admin, :post] then it would go to /admin/posts/new. Use @post. There's a massive difference.

Comment: Ryan, this is what i did: <%= form_for :admin, @post do |f|%> and the form's html shows /admin/posts/new

Comment: @Blankman: I'm pretty sure that it has to be an array, not just a list of the arguments :)

Comment: @Blankman: It works because the first argument of `form_for` is passed straight to `polymorphic_path`, which will interpret an array as hierarchy. `[@user, @post]` would become, say, `/users/1/posts/1`, since post #1 is nested under user #1, and `[:admin, @post]` becomes `/admin/posts/1`, since post #1 is under the admin namespace.

Comment: ok it worked with [], but the HTML just shows action=/admin/posts which is strange, guess it figures out the correct action on the fly somehow, don't understand this fully so that makes me nervous!

Comment: @Blankman: Sorry it took me so long to notice that comment :) That's exactly the path that should be produced. Check `rake routes`: `/admin/posts` with the `POST` method goes to the `create` action. That's always the pattern. Even without a namespace, it'd be `POST /posts` that maps to the `create` action.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with following routes

```
map.namespace :admin do |admin|
    admin.resources :posts
end
```